# How to create plot like in the picture?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfVLF.jpg)[enter image description here][2]

Somebody know how to create this?
the picture of the plot in the link,sorry

Comment: You should provide at least a sample of your data, the code you tried and what you got with that, please

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ggplot` with `facet_wrap` to create a similar one

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = date, y = temp, color = categ)) + 
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ categ2) + 
    theme_bw()
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'), length.out = 400, 
   by = 'day'), temp = sample(0:50, 400, replace = TRUE),
  categ = sample(letters[1:3], 400, replace = TRUE), 
  categ2 = rep(c("Dartmoor", "Hartmoor", "Eartmoor", "Cartmoor"), each = 100))
```